# How to get all events on all DOM elements of a page visited by Puppeteer - basically getEventListeners

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cdp

I am working on some Puppeteer powered website analytics and would really need to list all events on a page.

It's easy with "normal" JavaScript, so I thought I could just evaluate it in the Puppeteer and get to other tasks.

Well - it is not so easy and "getEventListeners" is not working for example. So this code below is not working (but if I take the code that gets valuated, copy it to browser's console and run - it works well);

```
exports.getDomEventsOnElements = function (page) {

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        let events = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let eventsInDom = [];
            const elems = document.querySelectorAll('*');
            for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
                const element = elems[i];
                const allEventsPerEl = getEventListeners(element);
                if(allEventsPerEl){

                  const filteredEvents = Object.keys(allEventsPerEl).map(function(k) {
                    return { event: k, listeners: allEventsPerEl[k] };
                  })

                  if(filteredEvents.length > 0){
                    eventsInDom.push({
                      el: element,
                      ev: filteredEvents
                    })
                  }

                }

            }

            return eventsInDom;
        })
        resolve(events);
    } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
    }
  })
}
```

I've investigated further and it looks like this will not work in Puppeteer and even tried with good old JQuery's `const events = $._data( element[0], 'events' );` but it does not work either.

Then I stumbled upon Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) and there it should be possible to get it by defining a single element on beforehand;

```
 const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  const INCLUDE_FN = true;
  const { result: {objectId} } = await cdp.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
    expression: 'foo',
    objectGroup: INCLUDE_FN ?
      'provided' : // will include fn
      '' // wont include fn
  });
  const listeners = await cdp.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', { objectId });
  console.dir(listeners, { depth: null });
```

(src: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3349)

But this looks too complicated when I would like to check each and every DOM element for events and add them to an array. I suspect there is a better way than looping the page elements and running CDP for each and every one. Or better said - I hope :)

Any ideas?

I would just like to have an array of all elements with (JS) events like for example:

```
let allEventsOnThePage : [
   {el: "blutton", events : ["click"]},
   {el: "input", events : ["click", "blur", "focus"]},
   /* you get the picture */
];
```

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3618 can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious so I looked into expanding on that CDP example you found, and came up with this:

```js
async function describe (session, selector = '*') {
  // Unique value to allow easy resource cleanup
  const objectGroup = 'dc24d2b3-f5ec-4273-a5c8-1459b5c78ca0';

  // Evaluate query selector in the browser
  const { result: { objectId } } = await session.send('Runtime.evaluate', {
    expression: `document.querySelectorAll("${selector}")`,
    objectGroup
  }); 

  // Using the returned remote object ID, actually get the list of descriptors
  const { result } = await session.send('Runtime.getProperties', { objectId }); 

  // Filter out functions and anything that isn't a node
  const descriptors = result
    .filter(x => x.value !== undefined)
    .filter(x => x.value.objectId !== undefined)
    .filter(x => x.value.className !== 'Function');

  const elements = []; 

  for (const descriptor of descriptors) {
    const objectId = descriptor.value.objectId;

    // Add the event listeners, and description of the node (for attributes)
    Object.assign(descriptor, await session.send('DOMDebugger.getEventListeners', { objectId }));
    Object.assign(descriptor, await session.send('DOM.describeNode', { objectId }));

    elements.push(descriptor);
  }

  // Clean up after ourselves
  await session.send('Runtime.releaseObjectGroup', { objectGroup }); 

  return elements;
}
```

It will return an array of objects, each with (at least) `node` and `listeners` attributes, and can be used as follows:

```js
/** Helper function to turn a flat array of key/value pairs into an object */
function parseAttributes (array) {
  const result = []; 
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    result.push(array.slice(i, i + 2));
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(result);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); 
  const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();

  const result = await describe(session);

  for (const { node: { localName, attributes }, listeners } of result) {
    if (listeners.length === 0) { continue; }

    const { id, class: _class } = parseAttributes(attributes);

    let descriptor = localName;
    if (id !== undefined) { descriptor += `#${id}`; }
    if (_class !== undefined) { descriptor += `.${_class}`; }

    console.log(`${descriptor}:`);
    for (const { type, handler: { description } } of listeners) {
      console.log(`    ${type}: ${description}`);
    }   
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

which will return something like:

```
button.aside-close-button:
    click: function W(){I.classList.contains("shown")&&(I.classList.remove("shown"),P.focus())}
main:
    click: function W(){I.classList.contains("shown")&&(I.classList.remove("shown"),P.focus())}
button.menu-link:
    click: e=>{e.stopPropagation(),I.addEventListener("transitionend",()=>{O.focus()},{once:!0}),I.classList.add("shown")}
```

Comment: Looks very very promising, will make some tests to see how performant it is (this will be running on hundreds or thousands of URLs)

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly and I am surprised how fast it is. Needs more testing, but maybe you can PR it to Puppeteer :)

Amazing how fast is CDP. Will test with complex pages as well

Comment: Hi @DagEikesdal just curious if you have any comment a few years out how this worked for you. I have a similar situation and am also concerned about performance.